# Javascript Image Refresh

Tags: javascript, refresh

I am using the following code, to try and refresh two webcam images on my site.

```
var t_webcam = 60 // interval in seconds 
      image_webcam = "cam_1.jpg" //name of the image 
      function Start_webcam() { 
      tmp_webcam = new Date(); 
      tmp_webcam = "?"+tmp_webcam.getTime() 
      document.images["frontcam"].src = image_webcam+tmp_webcam 
      setTimeout("Start_webcam()", t_webcam*1000) 
      } 
      Start_webcam();
```

On the site i am calling the function using the following line of code

However when i load this onto the website i get the following error and it dosen't work,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

If anyone out there has some more knowledge on Javascript and would be able to offer some help i would be greatful.

Thanks 
Richard

Answer (score 2):

`document.images` is an array, so it will only accepted numerical indexes. You are trying to access it like a dictionary, passing `frontcam` as a key.

You can use `document.getElementById` instead if your tag looks like this:

```
<img src="sth.jpg" id="frontcam"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
document.images["frontcam"].src = image_webcam+tmp_webcam
```

is invalid, it should probably be something more like this:

```
 document.getElementById("frontcam").src = image_webcam+tmp_webcam;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `frontcam` is an ID?

Try replacing

```
document.images["frontcam"].src
```

with

```
document.getElementById('frontcam').src
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id="frontcam"` to your `<img>` tag if it doesn't have it yet, and try this code

```
var t_webcam = 60; // interval in seconds 
var image_webcam = "cam_1.jpg"; //name of the image 
function Start_webcam() { 
  var tmp_webcam = new Date(); 
  tmp_webcam = "?"+tmp_webcam.getTime();
  document.getElementById("frontcam").src = image_webcam+tmp_webcam;
  setTimeout(Start_webcam, t_webcam*1000);
} 
Start_webcam();
```